# How to create a diagonal matrix from another matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, block, diagonal

I would like to create a block diagonal matrix from another matrix.
Let's say the H matrix is a 4 by 4 matrix and I want to create a matrix that is 5 by 5 with the upper left part being the H matrix. and the lower bottom part being 5. The other parts in the matrix are all 0.
How do I do this? The following code is the code I tried but it is not working.

```
H_new= [H,0;0,5];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [blkdiag](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/blkdiag.html):

```
>> H = reshape(1:16, 4, 4)
H =

    1    5    9   13
    2    6   10   14
    3    7   11   15
    4    8   12   16

>> H_new = blkdiag(H, 5)
H_new =

    1    5    9   13    0
    2    6   10   14    0
    3    7   11   15    0
    4    8   12   16    0
    0    0    0    0    5
```

Comment: Now *that's* a nice solution!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Generate correct number of [zeros](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html) by finding the sizes of two matrices involved. Writing just `0` doesn't expand itself.

```
H_new =[ H  zeros(size(H,1),size(brm,2));    %brm=5
         zeros(size(brm,1),size(H,2))  brm];
```

^ Works for any two-dimensional size of `H` and bottom right matrix (`brm`):

Answer (score 1):

You can assign into a pre-allocated buffer:

```
H = eye(4);
K = 5;
output = zeros(size(H) + size(K));
output(1:size(H, 1), 1:size(H, 2)) = H;
output(size(H, 1) + 1:end, size(H, 2) + 1:end) = K;
```